# TypeScript InversifyJS: complex bindings for multiple implementations of interface

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

Sorry if the title is vague..

I have the following implementations of the interface `ILogProvider`:
`MultiLogProvider`, `LogInjector`, `AppInsightsLogger`, and `ConsoleLogger`

I also have a class `DeviceInfoManager`..

The expected behavior is:

1. MultiLogProvider takes in an array of `ILogProvider`, in this case,
   `AppInsightsLogProvider` and `ConsoleLogger`
2. `MultiLogProvider` gets injected into `LogInjector` and `DeviceInfoManager` (FYI, `LogInjector` has a dependency on `DeviceInfoManager`, hence the complexity)
3. Anything else requesting an `ILogProvider` should get `LogInjector`

I've tried a few different variations of `.when`, `.whenNoAncestorMatches`, and a couple other `.when*` functions, but I either end up with a circular dependency or the request just never resolves due to some seemingly indefinite resolution loop.

I'm fairly certain these 2 lines are right:

```
this.container.bind<ILogProvider>(TYPES.ILogProvider).to(ConsoleLogger).inSingletonScope().whenInjectedInto('MultiLogProvider');

this.container.bind<ILogProvider>(TYPES.ILogProvider).to(AppInsightsLoggingProvider).inSingletonScope().whenInjectedInto('MultiLogProvider');
```

What I can't figure out is what `.when` functon to use for the below 2:

```
this.container.bind<ILogProvider>(TYPES.ILogProvider).to(MultiLogProvider).inSingletonScope().when*????

this.container.bind<ILogProvider>(TYPES.ILogProvider).to(LogInjector).inSingletonScope().when*????
```

Appreciate any help.